# Show that for the QM harmonic oscillator $\langle m |x^3 |n\rangle =0$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, wavefunction

I have to demonstrate the following result:
$$ \langle m |x^3 |n\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\Psi_m x^3 \Psi_n =0 $$
Unless $m=n-3$, $m=n-1$, $m=n+1$, or $m=n+3$.

I tried using the normalized wave function $\left(\Psi_n =\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}H_n(x)}{(\sqrt{\pi}2^n n!)^{1/2}}\right)$ on the integral, but I couldn't get a result. I also tried to solve using linear algebra, but I was unable to develop correctly (using some results from the book Mathematical Physics, Butkov).

Comment: The answer can be found quite simply using the properties $x$, when represented in terms of raising and lowering operators

Comment: Your question is missing a critical phrase: “harmonic oscillator”.

Comment: If you don’t like raising and lowering operators, use the second [recursion relation for Hermite functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Recursion_relation) (which is equivalent).

Comment: @Buzz this was the algebra resource i was trying to use, but i got a little confused (mainly because of the notation, in my course we are using another notation).

Comment: @G.Smith I did it that way too and it worked, but I didn't know this recursion formula in terms of $\Psi$, I used the most popular $xH_{n}(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an easy problem to solve using the ladder operators. We recall that $|n\rangle \propto (a^\dagger)^n |0\rangle$ and ${\hat x} \propto a + a^\dagger$. Thus,
\begin{align}
\langle m | {\hat x}^3 |n\rangle &\propto \langle 0| a^m(a+a^\dagger)^3 (a^\dagger)^n | 0 \rangle \\
&=\langle 0| a^m [ a^3 + 3 a^2 a^\dagger + 3 a (a^\dagger)^2 + (a^\dagger)^3 + x a + y a^\dagger ] (a^\dagger)^n | 0 \rangle 
\end{align}
In the last equality, I have commuted all the $a$'s past the $a^\dagger$ using the commutator $[a,a^\dagger]=1$ which gives us some extra terms as shown above.

Now, here is the crucial statement: $\langle 0 |a^m (a^\dagger)^n | 0 \rangle \propto \delta_{mn}$. I am going to leave a proof of this to you.

Then, if you look at all the terms that appear above, we note that they are of the form
$$
\langle 0| a^{m+3}(a^\dagger)^n | 0 \rangle  , \langle 0| a^{m+2}(a^\dagger)^{n+1} | 0 \rangle , \langle 0| a^{m+1}(a^\dagger)^{n+2} | 0 \rangle , \langle 0| a^{m}(a^\dagger)^{n+3} | 0 \rangle , \langle 0| a^{m+1}(a^\dagger)^n | 0 \rangle , \langle 0| a^{m}(a^\dagger)^{n+1} | 0 \rangle  
$$
Then, using the crucial statement above (which you must prove) we see that unless $m=n\pm1,n\pm3$ all terms above vanish so we'll simply get zero. Non-zero answers are possible only for the values of $m$ above.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to develop this way, but I got stuck in some definitions and also in the notation.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the answer is much simpler when we don't focus too much on the calculus and just look at the algebraic side. Take as a simpler example, the expectation value $\langle m | x | n\rangle$. We know that the position operator can be decomposed into something proportional to $a + a^{\dagger}$, where these are the lowering and raising operators respectively. We also know that $a |n \rangle$ is proportional to an $| n-1 \rangle$ eigenket, and $n+1$ for $a^{\dagger}$. Since the eigenstates are orthogonal, then $\langle m | x | n\rangle \neq 0$ unless $m= n \pm 1$. In your case, we have $x^{3}$, which is slightly more complicated, but follows the same logic.